# How to force Querydsl path generation on a @ManyToOne object with @Transient

Tags: java, jpa, groovy, querydsl

I currently have two objects `ObjectA` and `ObjectB` and they're related to each other by @ManyToOne and @OneToMany. But because I don't want to update/delete `ObjectB` when `ObjectA` is updated/deleted, `objectB` is annotated with @Transient. When Querydsl is generating the Q classes, I'm noticing that `QObjectA` doesn't have the `objectB` path because of the @Transient field.

It looks something like this:

**ObjectA**

```
public class ObjectA {
    @ManyToOne
    @Transient
    private ObjectB objectB
}
```

**ObjectB**

```
public class ObjectB {
    @OneToMany
    private Set<ObjectA> objectAs
}
```

**Controller**

```
repo.findAll(QObjectA.objectA.objectB.isNull(), pageable)
```

And the error I'm currently getting is

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: objectB for class: com.xyz.package.domain.QObjectA
```

I've tried @QueryProperty, @QueryInit, and @QueryEmbedded so far but nothing's worked for me. **Is there a way to make Querydsl generate the path for @Transient objects?**

Answer (score 0):

Your mapping is invalid. `@Transient` is not allowed on any managed attribute. It doesn't prevent removal, it just prevents the field from being mapped at all. Even if QueryDSL generated the metamodel for it, the query would eventually fail because this mapping is meaningless to the ORM (for example Hibernate).

As `ObjectA` is owner of the relation, the `ObjectB` it refers to will not be removed by default if you delete `ObjectA`. Instead, it will remove `ObjectA` from the inverse mapping (`objectAs`) - so it will remove it from the list so to say. If you want to remove `ObjectB` with its `ObjectA`, then you have to specifically annotate the association with `@ManyToOne(cascade = REMOVE)` (or something that implies this, like `CascadeType.ALL`).

Now for the inverse relation it is a bit more subtle. When removing your `ObjectB`, you might actually want to remove your `ObjectA`. By default it would clear the association by setting it to `NULL`, but obviously, this might be prevented by a non-null constaint. If you want to remove your `ObjectA` with your `ObjectB`, you can map it through `@OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true)`.